# Bigquery + Firebase analytics: select table of yesterday

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm querying bigQuery like this:

```
SELECT 
  param1.value.string_value AS id,
  count(1) AS views,
FROM `projectname.analytics_id.events_20200808`,
  UNNEST(event_params) as param1
WHERE 
  event_name = 'myEvent' 
  AND param1.key='id'
GROUP BY 1
```

I would like to make this a scheduled query. Is there a possibility to make my table a variable (so I can query the table of yesterday automatically)?

```
projectname.analytics_id.events_20200808 -> projectname.analytics_id.events_VARIABLE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL option by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Here is the example:

```
DECLARE TABLE_NAME STRING;
SET TABLE_NAME=CONCAT("projectname.analytics_id.events_",FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""SELECT * FROM %s""",TABLE_NAME);
```